# 'grouping' real numbers in a column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table`, `DT` which contains a column `C` with real value entries that satisfy the inequality `0 < x <= 1`. I want to 'group' these entries by intervals of e.g. 10. Specifically, to all values `x` in `C` such that `0 < x <=0.1` I want to assign the value 0.1, to all values `x` in `C` such that `0.1 < x <=0.2` I want to assign the value 0.2 etc

Below is function I have written which I thought would allow me to do this (be easy, I am relatively new to R!).

```
r = function(x,N){

  v = numeric(10)
  for(i in 1:N)
    v[i] = i/N*(x>(i-1)/N & x<=i/N)
   v = v[v!=0]
  return(v)

}
```

where `N` is the number of intervals I require. However, the code:

```
DT = DT[,newC:=r(x=C,N=10)]
```

gives the following error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In v[i] = i/10 * (x > (i - 1)/10 & x <= i/10) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In v[i] = i/10 * (x > (i - 1)/10 & x <= i/10) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
...
10: In v[i] = i/10 * (x > (i - 1)/10 & x <= i/10) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Any help much appreciated! Cheers

Comment: Why don't you simply use `round()` or `cut()`?

Comment: Something like `ceiling(dt$C * 10)/10`??

Comment: Ok,  but what if I wanted a different number of intervals? For example, it is not immediately obvious to me how I would use any of the above functions to produce 13 intervals say.

Comment: Also, it would be informative to know (regardless of whether it is optimal) why my function doesn't work. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (faster) alternative is to use `findInterval`, which does a very similar job to `cut`, but avoids the to-`factor` and from-`factor` conversions

```
  z1 <- findInterval(x,y)
  z1 <- tail(y,-1)[z1]
```

And a bit of benchmarking

```
cutting <- function(){
  z <- cut(x,y,labels=tail(y,-1))
  #this generates a factor: 
  #you can convert it back to numeric
   z <- as.numeric(levels(z))[z]
  }

finding <- function(){
 z1 <- findInterval(x,y)
 z1 <- tail(y,-1)[z1]
}

microbenchmark(cutting(),finding())


##     Unit: microseconds
##       expr    min       lq   median      uq     max
## 1 cutting() 188.50 192.1175 193.6275 195.821 354.701
## 2 finding()  34.18  35.5140  37.5620  38.763  46.397
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try a line of the for-loop in your function, say with `i = 1` and `x = C`:

```
DT[,1/10 * (C > (1-1)/10 & C <= 1/10)]
```

you'll notice that you get a vector of the same length of `C`. The error is saying that you can't assign a vector of length > 1 to `v[i]`. It's a good idea to step through your function (using functions like `debug`, `traceback` and `browser`) to make sure you're getting what you want as the right inputs.

Here's a way to make your function work:

```
r = function(x,N){

  for(i in 1:N)
    x[x>(i-1)/N & x<=i/N] <- i/N
  return(x)

}
```

R has a built-in way of doing this, too:

```
#sample data
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(100)
#to organize your data
y <- seq(0,1,.1)
z <- cut(x,y,labels=tail(y,-1))
#this generates a factor: 
#you can convert it back to numeric
z <- as.numeric(levels(z))[z]
```